# Saving Text on UITextField after pressing Return or Done key

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Good day! I just want to know if how can i `make a default text for my UItextField`?

**for example**, i typed 12345 in my text field then after i press "`return`" or "`Done`" key on my keyboard it should stay there forever even i close the app, or power off my device.

Comment: u use in the NSUserdefault in -(void)textFieldEndEditing Method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save the contents somewhere, then. See [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for example, it is good for storing simple data. If you need to store more information, writing it to a file (or Core Data, or using another database) would be a better idea.

Pressing the button can be captured by implementing [`UITextField`'s `textFieldShouldReturn:` delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn%3a).

Answer (score 1):

saving the Integer

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSInteger
[prefs setInteger:12345 forKey:@"integerKey"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

Retrieve the integer

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSInteger
NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSCoding class two methods

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:_title forKey:kTitleKey];
    [encoder encodeFloat:_rating forKey:kRatingKey];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    NSString *title = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kTitleKey];
    float rating = [decoder decodeFloatForKey:kRatingKey];
    return [self initWithTitle:title rating:rating];
}
```

to save objects